# Errors i don't understand. C++ CLR (StrStrI) This is madness

Tags: c++, clr

**using managed C++ CLR x86**

> Error 3   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000054) "extern "C" wchar_t
>   * __stdcall StrStrIW(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (?StrStrIW@@$$J18YGPA_WPB_W0@Z) referenced in function "unsigned long
>   __cdecl Attach::GetTargetThreadIDFromProcName(wchar_t const *)" (?GetTargetThreadIDFromProcName@Attach@@$$FYAKPB_W@Z) c:\Users\ATOM-NA\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\Projects\Attach\Attach\Source.obj Attach
>
> Error 2   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000003)
>   Attach.mydll::GetTargetThreadIDFromProcName   c:\Users\ATOM-NA\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\Projects\Attach\Attach\Source.obj Attach
>
> Error 1   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000002)
>   Attach.mydll::Prepare c:\Users\ATOM-NA\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\Attach\Attach\Source.obj    Attach
>
> Error 4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" wchar_t
>   * __stdcall StrStrIW(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (?StrStrIW@@$$J18YGPA_WPB_W0@Z) referenced in function "unsigned long
>   __cdecl Attach::GetTargetThreadIDFromProcName(wchar_t const *)" (?GetTargetThreadIDFromProcName@Attach@@$$FYAKPB_W@Z) c:\Users\ATOM-NA\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\Projects\Attach\Attach\Source.obj Attach
>
> Error  5   error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals   c:\users\atom-na\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Attach\Debug\Attach.dll  Attach

## include

using namespace System;

```
namespace Attach
{
    public ref class mydll
    {
    public : bool mydll::Inject(LPCWSTR hackname);
    private : bool Prepare(const char * DLL_NAME); //Param causes error
    };
}
```

This function runs flawless in *regular* C++

This is my first time using C++ CLR.

Reference: StrStrI https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
PTSTR StrStrI(
  _In_  PTSTR pszFirst,
  _In_  PCTSTR pszSrch
);
```

i think the error is comming from the data type **const char *ProcName**

---

**After attaching shlwapi.lib**

> Error 2   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000003)
>   Attach.mydll::GetTargetThreadIDFromProcName   c:\Users\ATOM-NA\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\Projects\Attach\Attach\Source.obj Attach
>
> Error 1   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000002)
>   Attach.mydll::Prepare c:\Users\ATOM-NA\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\Attach\Attach\Source.obj    Attach
>
> Error 3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved
>   externals c:\users\atom-na\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\Attach\Debug\Attach.dll 1   1   Attach

Comment: It is a winapi function, you need to link Shlwapi.lib

Comment: I have linked to that lib, let me post my includes ( i should have ) sorry

Comment: #includes have nothing to with linking, only with compiling.  Use Project + Properties, Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies.

Comment: Okay i just did that, and i still get errors